# The icon from the sprite does not change when changing the style in Google Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, svg

I have the **icon.svg** sprite. It own two icons `#rect` and `#circle`. Here it is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <style>:root>svg{display:none}:root>svg:target{display:block}</style>
  <svg id="rect" x="0px" y="0px"  width="18px" height="18px" viewBox="0 0 18 18" >
    <rect fill="#00ff00" stroke-width="2" stroke="#000000"  x="2px" y="2px" width="14px" height="14px" />
  </svg>
  <svg id="circle" x="0px" y="0px" width="18" height="18" viewBox="0 0 18 18">
    <circle  fill="#ff0000" stroke-width="2" stroke="#000000"  cx="9px" cy="9px" r="5px"  />
  </svg>
</svg>
```

I use sprite as background image and select target icon by `id`. There is an example below.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <script>
        function OnClick() {
            var div_el = document.getElementById("div_icon");
            switch (div_el.className) {
                case "rect icon": div_el.className = "circle icon"; break;
                case "circle icon": div_el.className = "rect icon"; break;
                default: div_el.className = "rect icon"; break;
            }
        }
    </script>
    <style>
        .rect { background: url(icon.svg#rect) no-repeat scroll 0 50% transparent }
        .circle { background: url(icon.svg#circle) no-repeat scroll 0 50% transparent }
        .icon { width: 18px; height: 18px; float: left; }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div><input type="button" value="Change icon" onclick="OnClick()"></div>
    <div id="div_icon" class="rect icon"> </div><span>image Stack</span>
</body>
</html>
```

Icon doesn't change when I click the button in Goggle Chrome.

> **NOTE:** It reproduced only http protocol.

Comment: @RobertLongson That is not the case here. The HTML page has only the `background:url()` part, selecting what is shown is done by the `:target` selector in the svg file. I can confirm it works in Firefox, and in Chrome when using the `file://` protocoll. Both show _two_ requests firing for the svg file. But if you use Chrome with the `http://` protocoll, ony one request fires. This looks like a Chrome bug.

Comment: If it's a Chrome bug it should be reported to the Chrome bugtracker.

Comment: While at first this "sprite" technique looks clever, on second glance, it might not be. Beside the bug you found, it seems to depend on a request being sent to the server for each fragment identifier, which means it wouldn't work offline. There are several other proven possibilities to define SVG sprites, you should consider using one of those. Read an [overview](https://24ways.org/2014/an-overview-of-svg-sprite-creation-techniques/).

Comment: I tried "view" technique (`<view id='rect' viewBox='18 0 18 18' />`). But it also doesn't work with `http://`.